# How would linear voltage regulators behave in series?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

How would this behave in real life? When I simulate it, I get stepped voltages across the LVRs and odd output voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyybl7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What are you trying to do? Connecting the ground of one regulator to the input of the next makes no sense at all. If you join all the grounds and connect the output of one to the input of the next, this also won't make sense. Ignoring the great heat generated by dropping 15V to 3.3V with a linear regulator, the output of the first regulator would be 3.3V. The second regulator will try to regulate its input down to 3.3V as well, but it has a typical dropout voltage of 1.2V. This means its input must be >=4.5V to work.

Comment: I think they would behave very strangely. You should explain what your expectation is, and also what you are trying to accomplish so that someone can suggest another way to do it.

Comment: Just think about this. With the outputs unconnected, putting the regulators in series like this forces all three of them to have identical input and GND currents. I think this would guarantee that at least two of them will not regulate correctly.

Comment: Maximum GND current and minimum (typical) IN current are 120 uA and 5 000 uA respectively.   The fragment circuit does not bias any of the regulators properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically like asking "what happens when I randomly connect parts without any objective".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw no current then yes, you get stepped voltages as you "expect".
But look at block diagram in datasheet of LM1117:
[image]

What will happen when you start to draw some current? You can see some resistors connected to GND pin, right?
So, from your circuit you are not able to draw any current at all.